# sending Emai Over TLS still gmail gives warning

Tags: c#, email, ssl

I installed SSL on my mail domain (mail.example.com). And sending mail over TLS.
I am using below script to send Email over TLS. But gmail giving the warning **domainname did not encrypt this message** with open red lock

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("server");
mail.From = new MailAddress("mailid");
mail.To.Add("anything@anywhere.com");
mail.Subject = "My Subject";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Body = body;
SmtpServer.Port = 465;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserId", "Password");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Does it mean my mail domain is not sending email over TLS?
How can I resolve this?

Comment: I believe gmail referers to the server<->server connection. You first deliever your mail to your outgoing mailserver. Then that mailserver forwards the email to gmail mailserver (using mx information from the dns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually not about your application sending the E-Mail, but rather about the mail beeing forwarded to GMail from your E-Mail server via SMTP. Your E-Mail server might not use a secure SMTP connection to forward this E-Mail to GMail.

Comment: Exactly. I did nothing with code. My Hosting provider installed the SSL and activated TLS for every outgoing port of mail server. Thanks for the help :-)